# Building one way chat?

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a Windows 8 app using C#, part of it is One Way Chat. It will be for multiple users such as teacher and student. We want to use a chat room for every course.

Teachers teach different courses that include many students and students study different courses, so when the teacher and student open the course page, they will find a chat page specific for this course.

How can I build such a thing?

Comment: "chat room" - voice? or text? What are the various paths of communication allowed (student -> teacher; teacher -> student; teacher -> studentS; student -> student; student -> studentS; student -> teacherS;)?

Comment: text, student -> teacher.

Comment: Can the teacher ever communicate back to the student?

Comment: no the teacher can not communicate back to the student.

Answer (score 4):

One-way chat? Isn't that known as Email? Without the back and forth there's really no need for a real-time display of text. I could see a teacher using a standard policy of "if you have further questions, email me" being the digital equivalent of "If you have further questions, ask me after class".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend skinning the IRC protocol. This will save you a ton of time, give you a lot of flexibility, and it already supports one-way chat using the voice privilege.

Comment: Voice using IRC? Maybe XMPP would be a better recommendation.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine no it's the voice and mute, you can mute a chat and only those with +voice (or @opped) can speak in chat

Comment: i want a very simple thing because i still student i didn't learn this . simple so i can understand it and rewrite it.

Comment: I would be surprised if there wasn't a .NET library for IRC.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only one-way, implement a little embedded web server or xmlrpc server in the teacher's app. Then, each student can post a message or call an xmlrpc function to send a message to the teacher. All they need to know is the IP address of the teacher's machine.

You could also try searching the internet for "simple echo server". This is a common thing to build if you're new to network programming so there are lots of tutorials and example code. Typically it's a few dozen lines of code that simply echoes back whatever it receives. You can then modify the code to update the teacher's GUI rather than echo the data back.